# Swift Search in Sqlite Database

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, search

I have a sqlite database in Swift and I can access the data and query it but I can't find out the best option to make a SearchBar to allow the user to search data in it. 
When I search about this subject on Stack Overflow and on other sources it always refers to Android, so it doesn't seem to be a common thing in iOS.

Anyone has an idea of the best option to do it or a best option?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlite `LIKE` operator to search from the table.

In iOS, you can make query something like,

For example, you have table with animal's record and you want to find particular animal then,

```
  NSString *query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ANIMALS WHERE RECIPENAME LIKE '%@'", animalName];
```

So, user enters animal name in search bar and press search button and you can take that value as parameter in your query.

You can refer [Tutorial Point's tutorial about LIKE clause.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already knew about the query, it is more about the way to link this query with my database as I manage to search from an array, how do I replace the array by my database?

Comment: So you have the data in an array now, and you want it to be in the database instead?